# What is the proper way of upgrading Android app API level from 25 to 26?

Tags: android, mobile

A year ago, I created a simple app for school and with the launch of Android O, I aim to upgrade it to target the latest version (from version 25 to 26).

What is the process for upgrading my app to target the latest Android version? Is there a beginner-friendly guide or a checklist to ensure I don't miss anything during the update?

Thanks a bunch! I would greatly appreciate any advice or insights.

Comment: Set `compileSdkVersion 26` and `targetSdkVersion 26`. Done. Call it a day. Maybe upgrade some other libraries

Comment: Joking aside, any errors when you *tried* something like that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you already follow the [Migrating to Android 8.0 guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html)?

Comment: @cricket_007 Maybe I'm just deluding myself - but I thought there would be a more disciplined approach that must've involved some precise method of reading change logs before performing minute changes. Or is it just really that simple

Comment: Feel free to read changelogs, but usually it is just that simple. Download the SDK, update the gradle sections, and start testing on a few devices. Plus, there is a documentation link, as mentioned

Comment: @ianhanniballake you wanna post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html) you have to make some updates in your **build.gradle** file

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 26
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
}

// REQUIRED: Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest
// support library that is compatible with Android 8.0
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

**Note**  : You have to Remove broadcast receivers from your manifest file that are registered for implicit broadcast intents in your manifest file. You have to work with broadcast read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts)

Comment: thanks @Alan for accepting answer now if you want to good understanding of background services from [here](https://medium.com/til-kotlin/jobintentservice-for-background-processing-on-android-o-39535460e060)

Comment: creadits to @ianhanniballake.